# Can the potential depend on $\hbar$?

Tags: potential, schroedinger-equation, physical-constants

Are there any physically realistic situations described by a Schrodinger equation

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \psi + V \psi = E\psi$$

where $V$ depends on $\hbar$?

I know the total energies $E$ often or always depend on $\hbar$. I'm really asking about the non-constant part of $V$.

Comment: $\hbar$ is a physical constant. It never changes. So what does it mean for something to "depend on" it?

Comment: Another way of saying what the photon is saying is... no. The answer is no.

Comment: I can't deny that hbar is a physical constant. But it is sometimes treated as a small parameter: in WKB, in the correspondence principle, maybe elsewhere. I am asking whether this parameter appears in the potential in any realistic problem. I am not sure whether to trust your confident "no"s!

Answer (score 2):

The Coulomb potential:

$$ V(r) = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac q {r^2} $$

but the fin structure constant is:

$$ \alpha=\frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{\hbar c} $$

so:

$$ V(r) = \frac{\alpha \hbar c}{e^2}\frac q {r^2} $$

so the question then is what does it mean to depend on $\hbar$? Are you keeping the fine-structure-constant constant, and changing $c$...or what?

And if you're changing $c^2$, are you changing $1/\epsilon_0$, or doing it with $1/\mu_0$?

Comment: Only changes in dimensionless constants can have a "measureable" change, almost by definition. A universe where the fine structure constant is kept the same, but ℏ or c changes would be measurably identical to ours, because the sizes of the meter and kilogram would change to match. So the only meaningful way to "depend on ℏ" would be to depend on α, if we want to assume that has any meaning in the first place.

Comment: @AnthonyKhodanian I agree. Another perspective is this: $\hbar$ and $c$ are just unit conversions. They only have numerical values other than $1$ - the even only have symbols - because humans have chosen odd units for measuring length, time, and energy.

Comment: @AXensen ..or we've chosen odd units (really _any_ units) for speed and action.

Answer (score 1):

$\hbar$ does not have units of energy and it is a constant so it’s not clear what you mean by “non-constant” part of $V(x)$ but take

$$
V(x)=-V_0 e^{-m \omega x^2/\hbar}\, ,
$$
which depends on powers of $\hbar$ (and other constants).

Comment: Does this occur in a realistic problem? In a way it is similar to a delta function potential.

Comment: sure.  There are Gaussian potentials.  What is artificial is inserting $\hbar$.  Since it’s a number you can always write $\lambda x^2=\hbar (\lambda/\hbar)x^2=\hbar \lambda’ x^2$.